# What are the differences between Signaler and Primer pheromones?

Tags: endocrinology

I have searched few authentic books and have found the following difference between them.

Signaler pheromone induces fast reaction in the recipient and the Primer induces slow reaction.

But I did not find any book that discriminates their function.

P.S. I have read Wikipedia and I'm not counting on it.

Answer (score 3):

A good example of a primer and a signaler pheromone could be in the recently discovered pheromone system in pennate diatoms (unicellular algae). When diatoms reach a certain size as a result of successive divisions (they get smaller with each vegetative division) both mating types start to produce a first pheromone that provokes cellular responses in their mates: 1) to stop dividing vegetatively and 2) to produce either another pheromone (a cell attractant, by one of the mating types) or to induce a sensing system to locate their mates. So, the 'Primer' pheromone would be the first, and the 'Signaler' the second pheromone, i.e. the attractant. A similar system exists in fungi. The evolutionary explanation is likely that organisms don't need to invest in pheromones and their associated repertoire of sex genes when mates are not present.

References:

- [Metabolomics Enables the Structure Elucidation of a Diatom Sex
  Pheromone](http://onlinelibrary.wiley.com/doi/10.1002/anie.201208175/abstract)
- [Pheromone signaling during sexual reproduction in algae](http://onlinelibrary.wiley.com/doi/10.1111/tpj.12496/pdf)